# Statements about groups, monomorphism and epimorphism

Tags: group-theory, abstract-algebra

**Problem**

Let $f:G \to G'$ be a monomorphism. Determine if the following statements are true or false:

(i) $G'$ is noncommutative implies $G$ is noncommutative.

(ii) $G'$ is cyclic implies $G$ is cyclic.

Let $f:G \to G'$ be an epimorphism, is it true that if $G$ is noncommutative then $G'$ is non commutative?

I think that none of these statements is true (I've tried to show them and I couldn't), however, I am having a lot of difficulty thinking about counterexamples. I would appreciate suggestions to find counterexamples (maybe I am wrong and one or all of them are true).

Comment: To say that $f$ is a monomorphism means that $f$ is an injective group homomorphism, $i.e.$, an embedding of $G$ in $G'$.  Hint:  identify $G$ with its image $f[G]\leq G'$.

Comment: For (i), consider the symmetric group $S_3$ and corresponding alternating group $A_3\leq S_3$.

Comment: So, for (ii), I have that $G \cong Im(G)$, and since $Im(G)$ is also cyclic, then the image of the isomorphism $\phi:Im(G) \to G$, $Im(\phi)=G$ is also cyclic (if $<h>=Im(G)$, then $<\phi(h)>=G$. Am I correct?

Comment: Indeed you are correct.

Comment: Another counterexample to (i) can be seen as follows:  the Klein 4-group $V_4$—which is an elementary Abelian $2$-group—embeds in the symmetric group $S_4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Counterexample: the identity homomorphism $\;A_3\to S_3\;$ is a monomorphism from the abelian (in fact, cyclic) group $\;A_3\;$ into the non-abelian group $\;S_3\;$

(ii) True, since a monomorphism embed a group as a subgroup of another, and all the subgroups of a cyclic one are cyclic.

(iii) False also, since the trivial homomorphism $\;G\to \{1\}\;$ is onto from **any** group $\;G\;$ , so choose your favourite non-abelian $\;G\;$ to provide a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Only the first and third statements are false: for both of these, consider the short exact sequence

$$1 \to \mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z} \cong A_3 \to S_3 \xrightarrow{\text{sgn}} \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \cong \{\pm 1\} \to 1$$

For (ii), use the fact that a subgroup of a cyclic group is cyclic.

Comment: I'm not sure using short sequences is the appropiate level for someone asking such a basic question.

Comment: @Timbuc: The term "short exact sequence" is irrelevant: what is important are the properties of the maps, namely being a monomorphism/epimorphism. Also, I wouldn't necessarily expect someone using category-theoretic terms to be at such a basic level

Comment: I doubt whether a beginner in group theory would even know what is going on with your diagram. And what category-theoretic terms are you talking about?

Comment: @Timbuc: monomorphism/epimorphism are category-theoretic terms. In beginning group theory, one would normally refer to just injections/surjections

Comment: monomorphism/epimorphism are usual terms in basic group theory, too. I never studied category theory (I refused back then, I refuse now and most probably I will continue to refuse to study that)

Comment: @Timbuc: If you refuse to study a branch of mathematics that is your own decision. However even the proper definition of a monomorphism requires category theory - it happens that in the category of groups, mono = injection, but this is a coincidence (thus, to be honest one cannot even answer this basic question without knowing some category theory, i.e. the definitions of mono/epi)

Comment: @zen - Who is to say that the student learned the "proper" definition of epi-/monomorphism though? Perhaps their professor simply taught that a monomorphism is an injective homomorphism of groups, and similarly for epimorphism.

Just because they're using these words doesn't mean that they were given in full generality.

Comment: @SimonRose: That does seem to be the case here. Personally, I would not mix the two terms - it simply seems unnecessary to introduce the word monomorphism if one actually means injection (and doing this may also cause confusion to students later)

Answer (score 1):

Monomorphisms-

i) $S_2$ is a subgroup of $S_3$ so there is a monomorphism from $S_2$ to $S_3$. Now $S_3$ is noncommutative (you should use nonabelian) but what about $S_2$?

ii) It is true, because a monomorphism means $G$ is embedded inside $G'$ and if $G'$ is cyclic, what do we know about its subgrous?(Fundamentl theorem of cyclic groups)

Epimorphisms Case-

Consider $f$: $S_4$$\to$ $\mathbb{Z_2}$ such that even permutations goes to 1 and odd ones goes to $-1$. So It Not true.